# How can i filter the relationship between parents and child?

Tags: python, html, django

Here is my code:

```
\\models
class ParentsProfile(models.Model):
    Fathers_Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    Fathers_Middle_Initial = models.CharField("Middle Initial",max_length=500,null=True,blank=True, 
    help_text="Father")
    Fathers_Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)

class ChildProfile(models.Model):
     Firstname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
     Middle_Initial = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
     Lastname = models.CharField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
     Parent_Users = models.ForeignKey(ParentsProfile, related_name='+', 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,)

\\and this is my view
def Parents_login_form(request):
    students = StudentProfile.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Homepage/parentsprofile.html', {"students": students})
```

How do I filter the relationship between parents and their children?

And how to display it in html?

Please help me....

Comment: Can you be more specific on what the desired outcome is? Do you want to display all the parents with all their children or do you want to display all the children on a single parents detail view?

Comment: i want to display single parents with their all children

Comment: Looking at your view name it looks like the parent needs to log into a profile? If that is the case you can use `request.user` to access the logged in parent and then filter the students based on that.

Comment: yes, after the parents login, tell me how to do it

Comment: That is a completely different question. You will have to extend the Django auth model. I would recommend logging a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that StudentProfile is equal to ChildProfile

```
def Parents_login_form(request):
    students = StudentProfile.objects.all()
    return render(....)
```

in HTML file

```
{% for each in students %}
   Parent : {{each.parentsprofile_set.Fathers_Firstname}}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward